# The new Default Toolbar in 13.1 may have a bug in which a label appears over it. Can label be removed?

Tags: gui-construction, cells, menu, docked-cell

***This post does not ask how to stop new toolbar from appearing but how to remove the described label above it.***

I finally installed 13.1 and to my surprise Wolfram added a new `Default Toolbar` which appears to have a nice-rounded mix of common menu tasks. My only problem with it is the big useless label above it `NotebookToolbar` which almost doubles the toolbar's height. Right now I primarily use Mathematica on a desktop with a large enough screen, however there are times when my only access to it is on a laptop which has a much smaller screen.

Assuming it's a `DockedCell` using a `CellLabel`, can it be forced or set not to display this label?

---

**Edit:** A bug report was sent to Wolfram. When their feedback arrives
an answer shall be created with results. I'm using Windows 10 and here is a screenshot. Of the two toolbars, the top one is my own. The bottom one is the new Default toolbar in question.

[image: screenshot showing toolbars and label]

Comment: This looks more like a rant rather than a question. Perhaps it could be trimmed down to just the main point?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. Neither on Windows10, Debian 11 nor Linux Mint, there is a label above the toolbar. What system you are running Mathematica 13.1 on? Can you send a screenshot, showing the problem?

Comment: Can’t you just turn it off?

Comment: @HansOlo good point. my bad

Comment: @Tschibi i shall edit answer with an image. im starting to think its a bug if others dont see it.

Comment: @DrMrstheMonarch of course i can but that misses the point

Comment: Nice rant ***&*** question. Consider posting in Community. :)

Comment: Can you provide the value of `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells]`, as well as the contents of the modified stylesheet? This looks like something went wrong with your customization of the toolbars

Comment: Do you have your internet connection or data updates disabled in the Preferences dialog?  There was a bug in the original release of 13.1.0 that allowed a notebook-wide setting of `ShowCellTags->True` to affect the toolbar.  But we shipped out a paclet update that fixed that bug (among others) months ago.  All copies of Mathematica should automatically download and use the paclet update, unless you've disabled internet connections and/or updating.